# Problems with requirement.txt when deploying flask app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my web app built with flask in python to elastic beanstalk. This is the first time I use this service and I am trying to upload it from the console of AWDS. However, the log file displays errors with the file requirements.txt, which I created from my local computer by typing "pip freeze > requirements.txt". This created me a 360 lines requirements file (is it not too much?) and the log displays errors like this one all the time like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------

2020/11/10 09:22:02.505005 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
 

2020/11/10 09:22:02.505022 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2020/11/10 09:22:02.505119 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1605000122,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1605000122,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

---------------------------------------------------------
```

I deleted the entry "anaconda-client==1.7.2" and still does not work.  Same problem as well with anaconda-navigator==1.9.12, anaconda-project==0.8.3, Automat==20.2.0... I erased them all but there is always a new wrong requirement.

I guess the requirements.txt file is just wrong... any ideas to solve the problem? Did I
create the requirements.txt correctly? Might it be any kind of problem with the enviroments?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you ssh into your EB instance, and try running pip manually. This can help you better understand why it fails.

Comment: when I type pip install requirements.txt in my EB instance it displays  Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requirements.txt
  and it does not allow me to install pip

Comment: Can you post your `requirements.txt`? Also what EB environment version are you using?

Comment: I solved it by installing the 4 most common libraries: numpy, pandas, sklearn, flask. Using pip freeze pointed around 350 libraries, most of them were not even required for my project.